# Extract Values from simple html file via grep/awk

Tags: awk, grep, html

I have another grep/awk/sed issue within the attached HTML code below.

Given is a simple HTML file with table inside. The HTML is generated by a smart meter (household energy meter). Inside the html table, 2 values are presented that are important to myself: Pplus and Pminus. These are the actual power from the GRID and actual power coming from my solar plant.

I would like to grab these two values separately  as "stable/secure" manner as possible to be less error prone. My understanding is that the html structure never changes. As a starting point to find the values, `18.000` means 18W current power from the energy grid and `0.00000` means 0W currently produced from my solar plant (its night).

For myself it is almost impossible to find some structure that can help to grab the right position, I really appreciate your expert view here and if it is possible to make this work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>NK-FW graphic by Lingg & Janke</TITLE>
<LINK REL="apple-touch-icon" HREF="/NKFW_icon57.png">
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="NK-FW graphic by Lingg & Janke">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-control" CONTENT="no-cache">

<BASE TARGET="_top">

<STYLE TYPE="text/css">

BODY  {margin-left:0; margin-right:0; margin-top:0;}

A     {font-family:Arial; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; }
TABLE {font-family:Arial; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; }

INPUT {font-family:Arial; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#000000; }
SELECT{font-family:Arial; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#000000; }

.inputwidth  {width:190px;}
.keywidth    {width:190px;}

#idLJheadDiv {
               position:absolute;
               width:960px;
               height:50px;
               top:10px;
               left:0px;
               padding:0px;
               margin:0px;
               border:0px;
               background-color:#0074B2;
             }
#idLJheadTd1 {
               font-size:30px;
               font-family:Arial;
               font-weight:bold;
               font-style:normal;
               color:#FFFFFF;

               height:50px;
               text-align:left;
               vertical-align:middle;
             }
#idLJheadTd2 {
               font-size:20px;
               font-family:Arial;
               font-weight:bold;
               font-style:normal;
               color:#FFFFFF;

               height:50px;
               text-align:center;
               vertical-align:middle;
             }
#idLJheadTd3 {
               font-size:30px;
               font-family:Arial;
               font-weight:bold;
               font-style:italic;
               color:#FFFFFF;

               height:50px;
               text-align:right;
               vertical-align:middle;
             }


#idLJfootDiv {
               position:absolute;
               width:960px;
               height:50px;
               top:600px;
               left:0px;
               padding:0px;
               margin:0px;
               border:0px;
               background-color:#0074B2;
             }
#idLJfootTd  {
               font-size:30px;
               font-family:Arial;
               font-weight:bold;
               font-style:italic;
               color:#FFFFFF;

               height:50px;
               text-align:left;
               vertical-align:middle;
             }


#idButtonDiv {
               position:absolute;
               width:228px;
               height:50px;
               padding:0px;
               margin:0px;
               border:0px;
               background-color:#2f2f2f;
             }

#idButtonTd  {
               height:50px;
               vertical-align:middle;
             }

</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<!-- ************************** -->

<BODY SCROLL="auto"
      onResize="DoReposition();"
      onLoad="DoReposition();"
      BGCOLOR="#000000"
      TOPMARGIN=0
      LEFTMARGIN=0
      LINK=#ffffff
      VLINK=#ffffff
      ALINK=#ffffff >

<!-- ************************** -->

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
function HOffset()
{
   var window_width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : (document.body.clientWidth ? document.body.clientWidth : 0);
   return Math.max( 0, Math.floor( (window_width - 960) / 2 ) - 0 ).toString();
}

function VOffset()
{
   var window_height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : (document.body.clientHeight ? document.body.clientHeight : 0);
   return 0;
}

document.write( "<DIV ID='IDAlignPage' style='position:absolute; top:" + VOffset() + "px; left:" + HOffset() + "px;'>&nbsp;" );

function DoReposition()
 {var o='IDAlignPage';
   if(is_dom2&&document.getElementById(o))
    {var e=document.getElementById(o);e.style.left=HOffset()+'px';e.style.top=VOffset()+'px';}
   else if(is_ie&&is_major>=4&&eval('document.all.'+o))
    {var e=eval('document.all.'+o);e.style.left=HOffset()+'px';e.style.top=VOffset()+'px';}
   else if(is_nav&&is_major>=4&&eval('document.'+o))
    {var e=eval('document.'+o);e.left=HOffset();e.top=VOffset();}
 }

window.onresize=DoReposition;
window.onload=DoReposition;

//-->
</SCRIPT>








<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** upper + lower bar  *** -->

<DIV ID="idLJheadDiv">
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0" WIDTH=100%><TR>
    <TD ID="idLJheadTd1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Smart Metering</TD>
    <TD ID="idLJheadTd2">
      SA
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      21.06.2014
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      21:57:02
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      KW25
    </TD>
    <TD ID="idLJheadTd3">Lingg &amp; Janke&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR></TABLE>
</DIV>

<DIV ID="idLJfootDiv">
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0" WIDTH=100%><TR>
    <TD ID="idLJfootTd">&nbsp;&nbsp;Energy Analyzer</TD>
  </TR></TABLE>
</DIV>


<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** 1. row *************** -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:78px; left:0px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
P&#043; in Watt

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:78px; left:244px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:78px; left:488px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:78px; left:732px;" ALIGN="CENTER" >
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** 2. row *************** -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:143px; left:0px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
18.000

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:143px; left:244px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
<form action="g1.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" name="A" value="MykWh">
</form>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:143px; left:488px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
<form action="g2.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" name="A" value="Supply">
</form>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:143px; left:732px;" ALIGN="CENTER" >
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** 3. row *************** -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:208px; left:0px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
P- in Watt

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:208px; left:244px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
<form action="g3.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" name="A" value="G 3">
</form>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:208px; left:488px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
<form action="g4.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" name="A" value="G 4">
</form>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:208px; left:732px;" ALIGN="CENTER" >
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** 4. row *************** -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:273px; left:0px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
0.00000

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:273px; left:244px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
<form action="g5.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" name="A" value="G 5">
</form>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:273px; left:488px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
<form action="g6.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" name="A" value="G 6">
</form>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:273px; left:732px;" ALIGN="CENTER" >
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
P&#043;

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** 5. row *************** -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:338px; left:0px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:338px; left:244px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
<form action="g7.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" name="A" value="G 7">
</form>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:338px; left:488px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
<form action="g8.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" name="A" value="G 8">
</form>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:338px; left:732px;" ALIGN="CENTER" >
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** 6. row *************** -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:403px; left:0px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:403px; left:244px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:403px; left:488px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:403px; left:732px;" ALIGN="CENTER" >
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** 7. row *************** -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:468px; left:0px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:468px; left:244px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:468px; left:488px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:468px; left:732px;" ALIGN="CENTER" >
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- ************************** -->
<!-- *** 8. row *************** -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:533px; left:0px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

<form action="/index.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" value="ZURCK" name="A">
</form>

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" STYLE="top:533px; left:244px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:533px; left:488px;" ALIGN="CENTER">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<DIV ID="idButtonDiv" style="top:533px; left:732px;" ALIGN="CENTER" >
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"><TR><TD ID="idButtonTd">

<form action="/mainset/mainset.htm" method="GET">
<input type="submit" class="keywidth" value="EINRICHTEN" name="A">
</form>

</TD></TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
<!-- -->


<!-- ************************** -->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

I have tried the commands mentioned above but they don't seem to work.

The comment below, about python, how would that work, can somebody please give me a helping hand? I do not have any preference, but of course prefer the best solution that seems state of the art in all directions (speed, efficiency, ....)

The posted HTML does not change, only the values of course update every 10secs.

Comment: It seems that the same value of an `ID` attribute appears several times...

Comment: Parsing HTML with awk/grep is not so great.
Consider using a HTML parser: http://superuser.com/questions/507344/command-line-tool-to-query-html-elements-linux

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is [n̲̠̣̝̤̣̟̫͍͑͌́͆͗ͭ͋͡o̭̗ͩ͘ͅt̡̫̞̓̎͞ ͮ͊͛̿ͪ̌͊ͭ̐҉̧͉̱r̮̲ͮ͡e̸̲͓̫͔͎͖͊̿̌ͭͭ̽͗͋̆c̙͊̇͜͡o̴̼̹͒͊̆̔́͜m̤͈̦̝͎͇͓͊͗͐̃̀ͅm̠̆̅ͤ͗̽̇e̔̇̊͏̵̜̱͈͘ņ͎̬̲̫̗̹̭̩̤͂̌̎ͭ͒ͭ̍̊d̢̛͓͇̻̩̪̟͂̾ȩ̷̟͈̦͚̭ͮͮ̄͌̍ͅd̡̰̖̃́ͫͦ̋̅](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Why not use an HTML parser in Perl/Python/Ruby/…?

Comment: Please explain how the answers you got fail. They both work fine on the example you gave.

Answer (score 3):

```
> awk '/ID="idButtonTd"/ {printline=1; next;}; 
   printline==1 && /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ { print $0; }; { printline=0; }' file
18.000
0.00000
```

Answer (score 2):

If the html structure is indeed constant, then the following should work:

```
totalValues=$(grep -A1 "idButtonTd" yourfile | grep -v "idButtonTd" | grep -v "\-\-" | grep "^[0-9][0-9]*")
Pplus=$(echo $totalValues | awk '{ print $1 }')
Pminus=$(echo $totalValues | awk '{ print $2 }')
echo "Pplus = $Pplus"
echo "Pminus = $Pminus"
```

Comment: I added the closing parentheses that I omitted from the Pplus and Pminus variable assignment lines.  @njordan Running this on your dropbox file now seems to work correctly.